# What are good Perl Pattern-matching / Regex Modules?

Tags: regex, perl, module, cpan

I've been having a need to do a lot of regex / pattern-matching stuff lately and, in looking at different examples / forum posts from my web searches it seems people sometimes mention that perl has good modules to help in simplifying pattern matching / regex tasks, however they neglect to mention which ones are the best for this.. I have looked at CPAN for this but their site isn't very easy to navigate as I can't seem to search effectively by category.. any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at [Regexp::Common](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Regexp-Common/)

Also, look at [YAPE::Regex::Explain](http://search.cpan.org/~pinyan/YAPE-Regex-Explain-3.011/Explain.pm) and the [web front end](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl) to it. Invaluable.

Comment: Also reading mastering regular expression becomes a must when you want to do a lot with Regex.

Comment: Yes, Friedl explain RE very well. Here is a link: http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1279289368&sr=8-1

Answer (score 4):

Might I suggest the perl6-esque [Regexp::Grammars](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Regexp-Grammars/lib/Regexp/Grammars.pm) if you're doing anything really complex and need to write a grammar -- it is really awesome. I just used it to parse a few SQL commands for my perl postgresql shell: [pgperlshell](http://github.com/EvanCarroll/pgperlshell)

Answer (score 2):

A lot of the power of regular expressions is available natively in perl. Probably the best way for you to simplify your understanding of perl regular expressions is to read the excellent perl regex tutorial at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html

Comment: +1 for the excellent reference to what should be the first read document.